# How to insert a 300MB blob in jdbc mysql without OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: jdbc, blob

I want to insert a blob of 300MB in mysql but I seem to fail at doing it. I get all the time OutOfMemoryError.

I've set the 
`max_allowed_packet = 500M` in my.cn.

Here is my code:

```
@Test
    public void testWriteBlobWithJdbc() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Memory is " + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024 + " MB");
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/lazy_lob?user=root&password=itismeDA02071986");
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into addresses(description) values(?);");
            Blob blob = connection.createBlob();
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(blob.setBinaryStream(1));
            bos.write(get300MBData());
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            preparedStatement.setBlob(1, blob);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (statement != null) {
                    statement.close();
                }
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Here is what I get:

```
Memory is 910 MB

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Blob.getBytes(Blob.java:132)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBlob(PreparedStatement.java:2934)
    at cgad.learning.hibernate.TestLazyLoadLob.testWriteBlobWithJdbc(TestLazyLoadLob.java:64)
```

So basically I have 910MB RAM but I can't insert a 300MB blob?
Also, I thought this was supposed to stream the blob into db, but it seems it gets loaded in the memory and may cause some problems?

Can you help out if you have worked with blobs, I'm kind of cluseless...

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

Don't get the whole 300MB at one time into one huge byte array. Write it to the blob stream a chunk at a time.

The Blob class does stream the blob. The entity that isn't streaming it is you.